# function not returning or appending to new list

Tags: python

I'm having trouble making my code return a new list that I'm making from the input.

```
def beagle(list):
    bg=[] #this is the list for beagles
    new=list.split(",")
    return new
    for i in new:
        if "beagle" in new:
            bg.append("beagle")
            return bg
        else:
            return bg
    return len(gr)

print(beagle("cat, dog, beagle, golden retriever, beagle"))
```

Even though I have "return bg" in both if and else statements, the output is returning nothing.

Comment: You  `return new` At the top of the top...

Comment: Your function never gets to `return bg` since you have `return new` before anything

Comment: Also, you always return on the first iteration of your loop, kind of making it pointless

Answer (score 0):

If I get the point, you need also to strip spaces (better not to call a list `list`):

```
[x.strip() for x in my_list.split(',')]
```

And don't return too early, also append `i` to list:

```
def beagle(my_list):
    bg=[] #this is the list for beagles
    new=[x.strip() for x in my_list.split(',')]
    # return new # <-- remove early return
    for i in new:
        if "beagle" in new:
            bg.append(i)
     #  else:
     #      return bg
    return bg
```

The result is:

```
print(beagle("cat, dog, beagle, golden retriever, beagle"))
#=> ['cat', 'dog', 'beagle', 'golden retriever', 'beagle']

print(beagle("cat, dog, golden retriever"))
#=> []
```

---

In case better to check before to start looping:

```
if "beagle" in new:
    for i in new:
        bg.append(i)
```

Comment: Also probably don't want to `return bg` until after the loop has finished

Comment: @SamHollenbach, I think so, edited. But we are guessing.

Comment: true, but as @juanpa.arrivillaga said the code as it is would always return after the first iteration of the loop, making the loop pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

**#1** remove this return statement otherwise the the below code of the functuin will not be executed

**#2** add a `" "`(space) after `","`(comma). if you split the string list (`"cat, dog, beagle, golden retriever, beagle"`) by `","` you get `["cat", " dog", " beagle", " golden retriever", " beagle"]` so you can split by `", "` instead. you will get `["cat", "dog", "beagle", "golden retriever", "beagle"]`

```
def beagle(list):
    bg=[] #this is the list for beagles
    new=list.split(", ") # <--- #2
    # return new <--- #1
    for i in new:
        if "beagle" in new:
            bg.append("beagle")
            return bg
        else:
            return bg
    return len(bg)

print(beagle("cat, dog, beagle, golden retriever, beagle"))
```